# How to use Jenkins to deploy a website

Tags: javascript, jenkins, babeljs, jenkins-workflow

Ok, so I have the following setup for the website I am working on:

- a git repository on GitLab (if it matters)
- a production server associated with my domain

Website architecture:

- Hack and HHVM (for which I have to run unit tests)
- Babel (which needs to be compiled to JavaScript on deployment)
- SCSS (which needs to be transpiled to CSS on deployment)
- configuration files which also need to be adjusted on deployment

**Example file tree**

```
.
├── index.html
├── bin
|   └── my Hack scripts
├── dev-res 
|   ├── style (SCSS files)
|   └── js (Babel JS files)
├── res
|   ├── style (transpiled css files)
|   ├── js (compiled Babel JS files)
|   └── other resosurces
├── tests/
├── vendor/
├── node_modules/
├── Gulpfile.js
├── package.json
├── composer.json
└── .gitignore
```

This is a hypothetical file tree of my project in my computer (so, the one for development). So I've got `composer.json` and the Composer dependencies, I have the `package.json` and the Node Modules, I have the not-compiled SCSS and Babel JS files.

For development and local testing, all the dependencies will be installed and all of these *raw resources* will be compiled and saved in the `res` directory, but they are added to the `.gitignore` so as not to pollute the repository.

**How should this happen?**

I hit `git push`. GitLab triggers a Web Hook to my Jenkins instance (I know how to accomplish this). Jenkins clones the repository in a *working directory*, fetches and installs all the dependencies, runs server-side tests and transpiles/compiles all the resources, deletes all the development resources (`*.scss`, `/dev-res/*.js`, `composer.json`, `package.json`).

I decided Jenkins would be a good solution for this sort of things since I can host it on my own server. I know my problem may be too complex for you to write an entire *tutorial* here, but I need some guidance, an outline of how this process should be handled and some good reads would also be appreciated.

Comment: Why downvote without any remarks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many ways to answer this, I can literally think of 5 off the top of my head. But in the interest of time and space let me give you the my best answer.

I think this will be better achieved using [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/). This link will help you get setup with that aspect. Next, you will need the [docker plugin for jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin)

Now let's configure your project.

You will need to do a freestyle build. After you enter your git repository information and credentials you will need to configure the build itself. As a side note, I would configure the workspace to delete at each build so the the package.json dependancies do not kill space on your build host.
Now the build configuration. I would like to think you have a place where your artifacts are being stored so my steps are using artifactory:

1. Creating a new build job in Jenkins is simple: just click on the “New Job” menu item on the Jenkins dashboard.

   - Freestyle build jobs are general-purpose build jobs, which provides a maximum of flexibility.
   - You can also copy an existing job, which is a great way to create a new job that is very similar to an existing build job, except for a few configuration details. ...
2. Add your Source Code Management

   - Choose Git
   - Add your repository link
   - Select the appropriate credentials
   - Select the appropriate branch
3. Build Environment

   - Check Delete workspace before build starts
   - Check Provide Configuration files

     - Choose `artifactory-npmrc`
     - In the Target field enter: `.npmrc`
4. Build

   - Add build step
   - Bring the menu done and select Execute shell
   - Enter in the following commands:

Now as you stated there is a lot more to this and I wold be more then willing to collaborate with you to get this done. If you have any questions please do not hesitate to ask

```
#!/bin/bash

npm install --registry=http://artifactory.com:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual
npm publish --registry=http://artifactory.com:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npm-private
```

5. Select Apply and then select save
6. On the left side of the dashboard choose Build Now

Comment: Hi! Would you please join me here? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36712/jenkins-for-website-deployment

Comment: Maybe we can make a set time for this evening. I am in the PST time zone (San Francisco, CA) but would be super excited to help you in any way. 7 PM PST to 9 PM PST works for me

Comment: I am on GMT+2:00 (Bucharest, Romania) so that would be tomorrow morning for me :) Thank you very much